# log4net - Check/get configured LogLevel in C#

Tags: c#, log4net

we configure log4net using log4net.config and AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = 
          "log4netGui.config", Watch = true)]
```

Now we need to get the configured LogLevel (LevelRangeFilter)

in log4net.config we have set as follows:

```
<levelMin value="DEBUG" />
<levelMax value="FATAL" />
```

in c# we can check every LogLevel like this:

```
Logging.Log.Fatal(string.Format("LogLevelDebug is enabled: {0}", 
      Logging.Log.Logger.IsEnabledFor(log4net.Core.Level.Debug)));
```

so we'd have to check for every log4net.Core.Level.xxxxx - isnt there a method which returns the configured logLevel in an array or something similar?

available levels are:

```
public static readonly Level Alert;
public static readonly Level All;
public static readonly Level Critical;
public static readonly Level Debug;
public static readonly Level Emergency;
public static readonly Level Error;
public static readonly Level Fatal;
public static readonly Level Fine;
public static readonly Level Finer;
public static readonly Level Finest;
public static readonly Level Info;
public static readonly Level Log4Net_Debug;
public static readonly Level Notice;
public static readonly Level Off;
public static readonly Level Severe;
public static readonly Level Trace;
public static readonly Level Verbose;
public static readonly Level Warn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private readonly List<Level> logLevels = new List<Level>
{
     Level.Alert,
     Level.All,
     Level.Critical,
     Level.Debug,
     Level.Emergency,
     Level.Error,
     Level.Fatal,
     Level.Fine,
     Level.Finer,
     Level.Finest,
     Level.Info,
     Level.Log4Net_Debug,
     Level.Notice,
     Level.Off,
     Level.Severe,
     Level.Trace,
     Level.Verbose,
     Level.Warn
};

public IList<Level> EnabledLogLevels(ILog logger)
{
    List<Level> levels = new List<Level>();

    foreach (Level level in logLevels)
    {
        if (logger.Logger.IsEnabledFor(level))
        {
            levels.Add(level);
        }
    }

    return levels;
}
```